# Azure devops notifications

Tags: azure, azure-devops

i am not able to figure out why notifications about new comments on work items are not coming to some of the users..Does it has to do something with the subscription type of the user?
It seems that all users that has visual studio enterprise subscription are getting the emails and all others(basic/stakeholders) not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your notification subscription, you choose 'Team members by role'. For this choice, only certain team members associated with the event are notified. For example, in your issue, it will only deliver email to users fits the filters 'Assigned to (current),Assigned to (previous),Assigned to (new),changed by,created by,authorized as'.

If you would like all team members received the notification, please kindly choose 'members of team'

[image]

you could see [Create an email subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/notifications/manage-team-group-global-organization-notifications?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-account-enabled#create-an-email-subscription) for more details.